# How to reason that $n^5 - n$ is divisible by 2 as proof for a consequence of Fermat's little theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

In my text book on Discrete Mathematics (I), we have a chapter that covers a bit of elementary Number Theory. In it we see the famous Theorem of Euler as well as the derived little theorem of Fermat. I understand these theorems and even the proofs that are given for them in my text book. There is however a specific step in the proof given for Fermat's little theorem that I do not understand. For the sake of completeness I'll write both the resulting theorem (derived from Fermat's little theorem) and its proof here as written in my text book.

$$
\forall n \in \mathbb N^* : n \text{ and } n^5 \text{ always end on the same digit.}
$$

The proof goes as follows.

Because Fermat's little theorem we know that

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
n^5 &\equiv n \ (\text{mod } 5) &\Leftrightarrow \\
n^5 - n &= 5q &\Leftrightarrow  \\
5\ &|\ (n^5 - n).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

On the other hand

$$
n^5 - n = n(n-1)(n^3+n^2+n+1). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(a)}
$$

As both $2$ and $5$ are divisors of $(n^5 - n)$ we can conclude that

$$
n^5 \equiv n\ (\text{mod } 10). \ \ \ \ \ \text{QED}
$$

I understand the given result as well as the theorems it build upon. I also can easily see that $5$ is a divisor of $(n^5 - n)$. As I keep the target in mind I also can figure out that the only missing part of this proof would be to figure out a way to show that $2$ is also a divisor of $(n^5 - n)$.

At first equation $(a)$  did not make any sense to me. After checking the case where $n$ is odd as well as the case where $n$ is even, I did find out that the equation results in an even number in both cases.

My question, sorry for the very long introduction, goes as follows:

Should I wanted to have proven this myself. What approach would have lead me to trying to factor $(n^5 - n)$ to the given equation $(a)$? In fact while it is easy fo to factor from right to left in that equation, I do not easily see how one would go from left to right? Probably I am missing some fundamental mathematical knowledge here. Can anyone please help me figure out how would exactly figure that out? Is it trial and error? Is it just knowing some specific concepts? What knowledge am I missing here?

Comment: $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2+1)(n^2-1)=n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$

Comment: "Factoring from right to left" would be called *distributing* (or some might say "FOILing"), not factoring. There are many techniques for factoring. In this case, we used a special case formula (which are factoring formulas that only work in special cases), which are generally difference of squares, sum/difference of cubes, and perfect square trinomials. (There is a homogenized geometric sum formula which generalizes the difference of powers formulas, generalized much further by cyclotomic polynomials, and the binomial theorem generalizes the perfect square formula.)

Comment: For quadratics, there is the "$ac$-method" if it factors with integers else the quadratic formula. There are methods for solving cubics and quadrics, which are still elementary and hand-doable but are cumbersome, but in some cases factoring-by-grouping works. Generally there is no way to solve fifth-degree or higher with radicals.

Comment: I think the book was assuming it was well known that $(x^k-1) = (x-1)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}+ ..... + x + 1)$. (It *is* well-known. Take a moment to play with it.  You will see it a *lot* in the future.  Obviously the first thing to try to factor out of $n^5 - n$ is the $n$ so $n^5 - n = n(n^4 -1)$.  Then we use the formula and get $n^4 - 1) = (n-1)(n^3 + n^2 + n + 1)$.  The book doesn't care about $n^3 + n^2 + n+1$ (which *can* be furthered factored).  It just cares about $n$ and $n-1$.  One of those must be even so the whole thing must be even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Also by fermat  $n^2 \equiv n \pmod 2$. so $n^5\equiv n^4\equiv n^3\equiv n^2 \equiv n\pmod 2$ so $n^5-n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

2) In simpler explanation of 1)  $n$ is either equiv $1$ or $0\pmod 2$.  If $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$ then $n^5-n\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod 2$ and if $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ then $n^5 -n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

3) But what the text is doing is factoring $n^5 -n = n(n^4 - 1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1) = n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2 + 1) = n(n-1)(n^3 + n^2 + n+1)$.

The $n^3 + n^2 + n+1$ will not be relevant.

But $n$ and $n-1$ are.  One of them must be even.  And if one of them is even the entire product is even.

Bear in mind "$n\equiv 0 \pmod 2$" and "$n$ is even" are the exact same statements.

=====

Arithmetic on $\mod 2$ is presumed to be very easy.

Keeping in mind $n\equiv 0 \pmod 2 \iff n$ is even and $n\equiv 1\pmod 2 \iff n$ is odd;

We actually learned *everything* there is to know about $\mod 2$ in elementary school when we learned:

$even\times even = even$

$odd\times even = even$

$odd \times odd = odd$

$even + odd = odd$

$even + even = even$

$odd + odd = odd$.

That is *EVERYTHING* you need to know.

.....

$n^k;k > 0$ is either $even^k=even$ or $odd^k=odd$.  Either way:  $n^k \equiv n\pmod 2$.

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial:

- If $n$ is odd, is $n^5-n$ odd or even?
- If $n$ is even, is $n^5-n$ odd or even?

Comment: Thank you for these follow up questions. You are absolutely correct with your hints, if I straight up calculate on paper both cases, using the substitutions $n = 2k$ (case 1) and $n = 2k + 1$ (case 2), I do indeed get that $n$ is even in both cases. I do have to say that while calculating case (1) was easy, computing case (2) was quite tedious and involved some combinatorics.

So while I am happy that asking myself these questions would have given me the answer as well. I do think that if time is of the essence it would be nice to know a quicker approach.

Comment: @glendc: if $n$ is odd, then $n^5$ is also odd, right? And the difference of two odd numbers is even. It's that simple.

Comment: $\mod 2$ is presumed to be near trivial.  Either $a\equiv 0$ or $a \equiv 1\pmod 2$.  It follows that $a^k\equiv a\pmod 2$.  Also $a + a\equiv 0 \pmod 2$ always.  (THat's not useful here but arithmetic on $\mathbb Z_2$ is supposed to be *very* easy.

Answer (score 2):

There is already one answer, however you can use fermat's little theorem in the following way:

> Fermat's little theorem states that if $a$ and $p$ are coprime, then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1(\text{mod} p)$ (and as fleablood pointed out $a^{p}\equiv a(\text{mod} p)$, whenever p is prime)

As a result, $n^5\equiv n\cdot (n^2)^2\equiv n^2\equiv n(\text{mod} 2)$, so $n^5-n\equiv 0(\text{mod} 2)$ and so your desired result follows

Comment: This is true if the *aren't* coprime too.  If $\gcd(a,p)\ne 1$ then as $p$ is prime, $p|a$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ is trivially true.  But if $\gcd(a,p)=1$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $a^p\equiv p \pmod p$.  So for primes $a^p \equiv a\pmod p$ will always be true no matter the $a$.

Comment: @fleablood You're right, I edited it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is even, then $n = 2k$ with $k\in Z$. Substituting, I obtain: $32k^5-2k$; in other words $2k(16k^4-1)$. This is always divisible by $2$.

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ with $k\in Z$. Substituting, I obtain: $(2k+1)^5-2k-1$; in other words: $32k^5+16\cdot5k^4+10\cdot8k^3+10\cdot 4k^2+5\cdot 2k+1-2k-1=32k^5+80k^4+80k^3+40k^2+8k=2k(16k^4+40k^3+40k^2+20k+4)$  that is still divisible by 2.

Comment: this way is error-prone:  should be $\color{red}{...+40k^2+10k...}$

Comment: Seems very difficult as we don't care about *any* of the arithmetic calculations you labored through;  We only care if the results are even or odd.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it's my error. Sorry.

Comment: @fleablood my calculations can be used to show that the result of that expression is always even.

Comment: Yes but it seems like a lot of work to get there.

Comment: @fleablood if you don't want to use $mod$ rules, this is an esay and very clear way.

Comment: Thank you for your time @matteo, as suggested by my comment on tonyk's answer, I indeed also took a perhaps naive approach such as this one, after he suggested those hints. It is a lot of work, but it does indeed work and did so fo me.

Answer (score 2):

To factor $n^5-n$, first factor out $n$:  $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)$.

Now use difference of squares:  $n^4-1=(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$.

And again:  $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$.

Putting it all together, $n^5-n=n(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$.

If $n$ is even, then $n^5-n$ is even, since a product with an even factor is even.

If $n$ is odd, then $n\pm1$ is even, so $n^5-n$ is even.

Comment: Alternatively there is the $(x^k-1) = (x-1)(x^{k-1} + .... + 1)$ rule.  Which is what the book did.  I personally prefer to put off using if $k$ is composite as it is hard to see if $(x^{k-1}+.... +1)$ is factorable.

Comment: @fleablood:  That works too, but OP tagged and asked about factoring, so I did; my factorization could show, for example, that $3$ divides $n^5-n$, though that's not needed for this particular problem

Answer (score 1):

- For the factorisation: it results from high-school well known formulæ:
  $$n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n^3+n+n^2+1).$$
- For divisibility by $2$: let's use congruences modulo $2$.
  *Lil' Fermat* says that, for every $n$, $n^2\equiv n\bmod 2$, so $n^4\equiv n^2\equiv$ and ultimately $\;^5=n\cdot n^4\equiv n\cdot n\equiv n$, so $$n^5-n\equiv n-n=0\mod 2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2x+2x=2y;2x+1+2x+1=4x+2=2z;2x+2x+1=4x+1=2y+1$$

from theses you can prove multiplication rules like odd times odd is odd. and if that second number is the same as the first, that's exponentiation if repeated. A power has the same parity as it's base can then be proved. $n$ is our base in $n^5$.